# How many number of unordered triplets $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ are there such that $a \in A, b \in B ,c \in C$

Tags: combinatorics

How many number of unordered triplets  $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ are there such that $a \in A, b \in B ,c \in C$

like for number of unordered pairs  $\left\{a,b\right\}$ such that $a \in A,b \in B$ are
$$|A|*|B|-{|A\cap B| \choose 2}$$
for example-
$A=\left\{1,2\right\},B=\left\{1,2\right\},C=\left\{1,2\right\}$
then all unordered triplets are
$$\left\{1,1,1\right\},\left\{1,1,2\right\},\left\{1,2,2\right\},\left\{2,2,2\right\}$$
so answer is 4

Comment: Unless there are further restrictions, the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ is equal to $|A|{\,\cdot}|B|$.

Comment: Do you rather want unordered triplets from $A\cup B\cup C$ with repetition allowed and such that each of $A,B,C$ is hit?

Comment: $(2,5)$ and $(5,2)$  are two different ordered pairs.  It means the order matters, not that the numbers have been sorted.